# Linear Relationship between 4 row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

x1=[1,0,-1,2]

x2=[2,3,-1,1]

x3=[0,-3,5,3]

x4=[0,3,-3,-3]

Find a linear relationship between them, enter suitable coefficients in the box:
_x1+_x2+_x3+_x4=0

I am deathly stuck on this question. I have tried putting it into a matrix and proceeding by means of Gaussian elimination, i get to:

|1,2, 0,  0|0|

|0,3,-3,  3|0|

|0,0,18,-12|0|

|0,0, 0,-24|0|

And can go no further, and cant see how getting any further would give me a solution.

Other than simply trial and error guessing i cant find any way to get to the answer.

The answer should be 0=4x1 -2x2 + 4x3 + 6x4

I just cannot make progress with this question, i can happily answer similar questions where the vectors add to make another vector, but with these being homogeneous i just cannot find the solution.

pls halp

Comment: You have  a mistake in Gaussian elimination. Check it again.

Comment: If there’s any solution, then there is an infinite number of them. Unless there’s a particular method that you’re meant to use or some convention for which vectors to choose as the basis of the null space, there’s no particular reason to expect that you’ll come up with the same answer as in the key.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: you must solve the system
$$\alpha x_1+\beta x_2+\gamma x_3+\delta x_4=0$$
for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$